# Question to a system of equations, rank two matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

given the system of linear equations

$\begin{array}{rrrrr}x_{1} & + & x_{2} & + & 2 x_{3} & = & 2 \\ 2 x_{1} & + & 5 x_{2} & - & x_{3} & = & 2 \\ 3 x_{1} & + & 6 x_{2} & + & x_{3} & = & 4\end{array}$

I found the solutions

$x=\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac{8}{3}-\frac{11}{3} t \\ -\frac{2}{3}+\frac{5}{3} t \\ t\end{array}\right)$

Now I should find another solution $\mathbf{x} \neq \lambda \mathbf{y}$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: You have a parameterisation of the set of solutions. Choose two values of $t$ so that the resulting vectors are not collinear.

Answer (score 0):

I always like to see these things geometrically.

The solutions you've found give a parametrization of a line $\ell$ in $\Bbb{R}^3$ which does not pass through the origin.

Notice that two distinct solutions $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ will determine a unique line, namely $\ell$ itself.

The condition $\mathbf{x}\neq \lambda\mathbf{y}$ for all $\lambda$ means that $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ are linearly independent or, in other words, the line they determine does not pass through the origin.

What does that tell us?

Comment: actually one should find distinct x and y, I actually found the general solution and to continue I had to plug in some values for t so that x and y are not multiples of each other